# How do I handle authentication with the HtmlUnitDriver using Selenium WebDriver?

Tags: java, selenium, webdriver, htmlunit-driver

How do I handle authentication with the HtmlUnitDriver?

Comment: Does [this](http://code.google.com/p/selenium/issues/detail?id=34) help?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try this in java seemed to work for me

```
WebDriver driver = new HtmlUnitDriver() {
    protected WebClient modifyWebClient(WebClient client) {
        // This class ships with HtmlUnit itself
        DefaultCredentialsProvider creds = new DefaultCredentialsProvider();

        // Set some example credentials
        creds.addCredentials("username", "password");

        // And now add the provider to the webClient instance
        client.setCredentialsProvider(creds);

        return client;
    }
};
```

Answer (score 2):

If that is the basic authentication that you need you can do this when creating a HtmlUnitDriver instance: (the code is in scala, but you can easily change it to java)

```
new HtmlUnitDriver() {
  override def modifyWebClient(client: WebClient) = {
    val creds = new DefaultCredentialsProvider()
    creds.addCredentials("user-name", "user-password");
    client.setCredentialsProvider(creds)
    client
  }
}
```