# How to use credentials provider in selenium with python?

Tags: python, selenium

With python I am trying to use the credentials provider to provide credentials when connecting to a website for automated GUI testing with selenium. I found the following [page](https://github.com/seleniumhq/selenium-google-code-issue-archive/issues/34) which explains how to do this, possibly for JAVA:

```
@Override
protected WebClient newWebClient() {
    WebClient client = super.newWebClient();
    DefaultCredentialsProvider  provider = new DefaultCredentialsProvider();
    provider.addCredentials("username","password");
    client.setCredentialsProvider(provider);
    return client;
    }
```

I am trying to pythonize is, but I run into problems, and I do not find the appropriate class name fr the  `DefaultCredentialsProvider`:

```
from selenium import webdriver as original_webdriver

class webdriver(original_webdriver):
    def newWebClient(self):
        client = super().newWebClient()
        provider = DefaultCredentialsProvider()
        provider.addCredentials("username","password")
        client.setCredentialsProvider(provider)
        return client
```

The error when running this script is:

```
  File "C:/Users/adi0341/PycharmProjects/SeleniumTest/tester.py", line 12, in <module>
    class webdriver(original_webdriver):
TypeError: module.__init__() takes at most 2 arguments (3 given)
```

How to fix it? Or how to do something similar as explained in that link? Maybe there is an altogether different approach to provide authentication in order to open a web page for selenium automated GUI-testing?

P.S: The authentication will be an essential part of the testing itself. Logging in as different users and check access rights...

Comment: Obviously you create class `webdriver` instance with 2 arguments (+self) instead of 1 argument (+self). Provide more code

Answer (score 1):

> **Step 1**

For this requirement use [keyring](https://pypi.python.org/pypi/keyring#downloads)

```
import keyring
keyring.set_password("https://my.sharepoint.come", "username", "password")
```

After this the credentials will be stored under credentials manager for automatic login, you can run this **`control /name Microsoft.CredentialManager`** command in a command prompt to get it:

[image]

Newly added credentials will appear under "Generic Credentials"

[image]

Further more even before you write the code you can test this manually.

> **Step 2**
>
> Once you are through with this, you need to set the preference of
>   Firefox to hold your url under
>   `network.automatic-ntlm-auth.trusted-uris`:

```
from selenium import webdriver
url = 'http://my.sharepoint.com'
fp = webdriver.FirefoxProfile()
fp.set_preference('network.automatic-ntlm-auth.trusted-uris',url)
driver = webdriver.Firefox(firefox_profile=fp)
driver.get(url)
```

Comment: Does not seem to work. I am not logged in with the correct credentials. The sharepoint webpage returns an authentication error.

Answer (score 0):

Can you point which line is 12?
I am unsure about your line with super, as in python inheritance of constructors looks like in [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14583761/typeerror-module-init-takes-at-most-2-arguments-3-given) example.

Answer (score 0):

DefaultCredentialsProvider ship with Java HtmlUnit, not webdriver.  So you cannot find it under webdriver (whether in Java webdriver nor Python webdriver nor etc webdriver)

check this reference : [How do I handle authentication with the HtmlUnitDriver using Selenium WebDriver?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11242723/how-do-i-handle-authentication-with-the-htmlunitdriver-using-selenium-webdriver)

Can you check whether there is similar python counter part for DefaultCredentialsProvider. Otherwise, the answer is : there is no DefaultCredentialsProvider for you in python.

Perhaps you should look for other authentication solution, such as this: 
[Authentication with selenium (Python)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24464631/authentication-with-selenium-python)